# Activerecord: map one to one and retain duplicates

Tags: activerecord

I have an array with User IDs:

```
UserID = [
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
3 
2 
2 
3]
```

I have a table that maps User ID to User Email. I'm trying to match IDs to Emails but retain duplicates so I end up with:

```
[
1@me.com 
2@me.com 
3@me.com
4@me.com 
5@me.com 
3@me.com 
2@me.com 
2@me.com 
3@me.com]
```

When I try to pluck or map it like:

```
UserInfo.where(:id => UserID).pluck(:email)
```

I end up with:

```
[
 1@me.com 
 2@me.com 
 3@me.com
 4@me.com 
 5@me.com]
```

How can I get the table I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop

```
ids.map{|id| UserInfo.find(id: id).email }
```

But of you have tons of ids you may want to optimize it by loading first just the records you need

```
email_hash = UserInfo.where(id: ids).inject({}) {|h, v| h[v.id] = v.email; h;}
result = ids.map{|id| email_hash[id]}
```